# Writing a memory buffer to std::stringstream

Tags: c++, stringstream

I have a class that represents a buffer in memory

```
class Buffer
{
public:
    Buffer(const char* buffer, size_t size)
        :m_buffer(buffer), m_size(size)
    {
    }

    const char* m_buffer;
    size_t m_size;
};
```

I need to overload `operator<<` on this class so that it can be written to a `std::stringstream` like this

```
char arr[] = "hello world";
Buffer buf(arr, 11);
std::stringstream ss;
ss << buf;
```

How do I do this? Note that the memory buffer might have `NULL` chars in between. Also, since the memory buffer can be large, I want to avoid making any extra copies of this (other than the copy into the stringstream).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Writing to a stream is always done to an output stream.

If you see e.g. [this `std::stringstream` reference](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_stringstream) you will see that it inherits from `std::iostream` which inherits from `std::ostream` (as well as from `std::istream`).

That means you simply overload it like this:

```
class Buffer
{
public:
    ...

    friend std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& os, Buffer const& buf)
    {
        // Code to write the buffer to the stream...
    }
};
```

This overload of course means you can use the `Buffer` class to write to *any* output stream.

Exactly what's needed in the overloaded function to write the data depends on the data. Can it be any generic binary data then you should probably use [`std::ostream::write`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_ostream/write). Otherwise you could just use e.g. `std::string` to act as an intermediate:

```
return os << std::string(m_buffer, m_size);
```

You of course need to make sure that the buffer is not empty, or a null pointer.

Comment: Can you please help me with what should go into this function (code to write the buffer to the stream)? Thanks.

Comment: I would like to avoid making extra copies of the buffer (into an intermediate std::string)

Comment: Inside the `friend` function's definition: `return os.write(buf.m_buffer, buf.m_size);`  A caveat exists because `write` takes a signed integer size parameter (type `std::streamsize`), whose bit count typically matches or exceeds `size_t`, so if you want to ensure support for very large buffers, you will have to check the maximum `std::streamsize` value, and if `m_size` is greater, break up the write operation into multiple chunks.

Answer (score 2):

Use `std::ostream::write`() in your `operator<<` overload to write the buffer to the `std::ostream`.

This will write everything, null bytes, et al.